# How do I add a variable for a filename?

Tags: excel, vba

I found code I managed to make work.

How do I add a variable for the filename which includes a wildcard?

Having set a variable for the filename, it's a little restrictive as some older files have slightly different names.

I'm struggling to mix the variable with a wildcard.

The variable is SelectedReport and all the reports begin with the same 3 letters followed by the same 3 digits 'REP009' it's beyond the initial report number that the filenames go awry.

How do I add a variable for the exported filename?

```
Sub RecursiveFileSearch(ByVal targetFolder As String, ByRef objRegExp As Object, _
                ByRef matchedFiles As Collection, ByRef objFSO As Object)

    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim objSubFolders As Object

    'Get the folder object associated with the target directory
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(targetFolder)

    'Loop through the files current folder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objRegExp.test(objFile) Then
            matchedFiles.Add (objFile)
        End If
    Next

    'Loop through the each of the sub folders recursively
    Set objSubFolders = objFolder.Subfolders
    For Each objSubfolder In objSubFolders
        RecursiveFileSearch objSubfolder, objRegExp, matchedFiles, objFSO
    Next

    'Garbage Collection
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objSubFolders = Nothing

End Sub

Function FindPatternMatchedFiles(sPath As String) As Collection

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Dim SelectedReport As String
    SelectedReport = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "B").Value
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")


    ' new line with filename
    objRegExp.Pattern = SelectedReport
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

    Dim colFiles As Collection
    Set colFiles = New Collection

    RecursiveFileSearch sPath, objRegExp, colFiles, objFSO

    'Garbage Collection
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objRegExp = Nothing

    Set FindPatternMatchedFiles = colFiles

End Function

Sub MergeWorkbooks(sPath As String, sWbName As String)

    Dim colFiles As Collection
    Set colFiles = FindPatternMatchedFiles(sPath)

    Dim appExcel As New Excel.Application
    appExcel.Visible = False

    Dim wbDest As Excel.Workbook
    Set wbDest = appExcel.Workbooks.Add()

    Dim wbToAdd As Excel.Workbook
    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    For Each file In colFiles

        Set wbToAdd = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(file)

        For Each sheet In wbToAdd.Sheets
            sheet.Copy Before:=wbDest.Sheets(wbDest.Sheets.Count)
        Next sheet

        wbToAdd.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Next
    wbDest.Close True, sPath + "\" + sWbName
    Set wbDest = Nothing
    Set appExcel = Nothing

End Sub


Sub Main()

    MergeWorkbooks "C:\Path\To\Folder", "Awesomeness.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add *exactly* the code you are using right now. We need to see exactly the code **you** are working on or a [mcve] that illustrates your issue. Some *similar* code is not enough, and the code must be within your question. Also try to ask a more precise question. See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: hopefully that's cleaned the question up sufficiently. Thanks

Comment: Your question is still a bit unclear to me. What is the variable you are talking about. Is it `SelectedReport`? So then probably you will need to show the pattern (value of `SelectedReport`) and an example set of filenames where we can see which match and which don't.

Comment: clarification added